# Implementing Pi algorithm in java

Tags: java, algorithm, bigdecimal, pi

I have searched the web for an algorithm that could calculate the value of pi in an efficient manner and I found this:

[image]

Using a calculator, I was able to calculate the first few digits of pi by hand. Then I knew that the formula works so I tried to implement it However, the output was no where near the value of pi. I then tried printing the value of `k` and the output every time I incremented `k` and found that the output was going from 3 to 10 then to 1 and so on. It would be appreciated if someone could point out the flaw in my program.

Here is my code:

```
 import java.math.BigDecimal;
 import java.math.MathContext;
 import java.math.RoundingMode;

  public class pi2 {
static MathContext mc = new MathContext(1000, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    BigDecimal root2=new BigDecimal("1.41421356237309504880168872420969807856967187537694807317667973799");
    BigDecimal a=(root2.multiply(new BigDecimal("2"))).divide(new BigDecimal("9801"),mc);
     BigDecimal ans=new BigDecimal("0");
    for(BigDecimal k=new BigDecimal("0");k.compareTo(new BigDecimal("2000"))<=0;k=k.add(new BigDecimal("1"))){


    BigDecimal num=fact(k.multiply(new BigDecimal("4")));
    num=num.multiply(new BigDecimal("1103").add(k.multiply(new BigDecimal("26390"))));
    BigDecimal den=fact(k).pow(4);
            den=den.multiply(new BigDecimal("396").pow(k.multiply(new BigDecimal("4")).intValueExact()));
    ans=ans.add(num.divide(den,mc));



    }
    ans=new BigDecimal("1").divide(ans,mc);
    System.out.println(ans);

}
public static BigDecimal fact(BigDecimal n){
    BigDecimal fact=new BigDecimal("1");
    for(BigDecimal x=new BigDecimal("2");n.compareTo(x)>=0;x=x.add(new BigDecimal("1"))){
        fact=fact.multiply(x);
    }
    return fact;

}

 }
```

Here is the output:

```
5.580282058008853402510559291287581867553431390145503640210100548605034743358097050034424720628698860929750569800058429421656020670208288633526864302454613600847940382311736134643671764886381747697190968564014260705233085812484714762274969350204069098619933375627715134891912898782601108729886146330332238253003691746047262799485039571747683663565532369064391166325006674455252331737698907670644446295854092826000968263741742613071668128325081312284036131088326091218220137819968277353340599533207728105864448598414581380099885134601317006991806489649924935353370069906252625046822796244633763704419705976717286963549896200415922555506633154441005278818242772512067320640614989708237011539020994102009040721602261875679359630595715795837939333694056692953617077290030676459281218578044754236976994457097401172359470109498529296892483489384488461202901916083392300861779680090077181505893710321463758029409577389297666918447580531492394294312022253607251169070143541696305881176305678794312168269627285E+15966
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If it's for studying purpose then cool, go on with it. if you just need PI in your program use `Math.PI`.

Comment: `ans=ans.multiply(a);` at the end of your loop shouldn't be there. That math should be done **after** the summation is completed.

Comment: ug_ yes, I know that was there from when I was debugging.

Comment: guillaume thanks for pointing that out however, it still doesn't work

Comment: I Try various k, and result doesnt converge. Perhaps modify your code to show each 10 (or 100) steps. Somewhere, there is perhaps some limitation inside variables ...

Comment: Strangely enough, when I run the above code with `ans=ans.multiply(a);` added after the } and before `ans=new BigDecimal("1").divide(ans,mc);`, I obtain pi as the answer...

Comment: @Foleosy look at ug_ 's answer

Comment: Yeah I did, previously (his comment), which is why I implemented it to test when you said it was there when you were debugging but still gave you the problem.

Comment: Please use `BigDecimal.ONE` (my preference would be `BigDecimal(2)`, too).

Comment: @Foleosy Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @greybeard oh I didn't know that, Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't applying the `2*sqrt(2)/9801` (`a`) at all to your equation. Essentially the variable `a` is not used right now.

Simply change the end of `main` method to read:

```
// i moved a down here because its not used above this location.
BigDecimal a = (root2.multiply(new BigDecimal("2"))).divide(new BigDecimal("9801"), mc);
ans = new BigDecimal("1").divide(ans.multiply(a), mc);
System.out.println(ans);
```

Running this on my machine prints out `3.141592`

Comment: Haha I had forgotten that Thanks!

Comment: @Paul You can help reduce problems like this from happening making some new habits in your coding. Try to declare variables only before they will be used and in the smallest scope possible. In this case declare `a` and `root2` right before you apply them. Also using an IDE will help out alot with keeping your code clean and finding bugs. For instance when I put this code in my Eclipse it quickly underlined the variable `a` telling me it was unused.

Comment: Thanks, I was actually using eclipse to code this but I didn't have that option on apparently.  Also, thanks for the tips, I will try my best to implement them :)